# GL-Enabling Texture2D in MonoTouch/OpenTK/GLKit generates error 0x0500

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xamarin.ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I'm using OpenTK-1.0.dll in MonoTouch 5.2.13 in a GLKViewController. I can render 3D objects using coloured vertices, everything there works fine.

Now I'd like to render 3D objects with texture maps. To accomplish this, I added the following call to my `ViewDidLoad` method (in my subclass of GLKViewController):

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
```

But since I added this call, the OpenGL screen stays black (no more coloured vertices), and on the Console I see

```
GL ERROR: 0x0500
```

When I remove the `GL.Enable` call, everything is working again.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, I had to add the following:

```
_baseEffect.Texture2d0.Enabled = true;
_baseEffect.Texture2d0.GLName = _myGlkTexture.Name;
_baseEffect.Texture2d0.EnvMode = GLKTextureEnvMode.Replace;
_baseEffect.Texture2d0.Target = GLKTextureTarget.Texture2D;
_baseEffect.PrepareToDraw();
```

The `BaseEffect` class takes care of managing the shaders, so we just have to tell it to activate the texture rendering.

Answer (score 2):

`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` (or the openTK equivalent) does not exist in OpenGLES 2.0. It only controls texturing for the fixed pipeline.

To use textures in OpenGLES 2.0, you just sample them in your shader, there's no need to enable anything.

Comment: How about http://games.ianterrell.com/how-to-texturize-objects-with-glkit/ ? Doesn't this website describe how to texturize in OpenGL ES 2.0 using GLKit?

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand what you're asking. @cheeesus

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you were saying that in OpenGL ES 2.0, there is no way to texturize shapes without the use of custom shaders. However, I think this website describes how to texturize shapes **without** the use of custom shaders. Doesn't that contradict your statement?

Comment: In **OpenGLES2.0**, that's correct that it is not possible to draw anything without using shaders. However you are using **GLKit**, which I am less familiar with. It's possible that GLKit is wrapping OpenGL and implementing shaders behind the scenes such that you don't have to create them. But in pure OpenGLES 2.0 shaders are absolutely mandatory for every draw. @cheeesus

Comment: OK thank you. I'm looking for an answer concerning `GLKit`, as stated in my question (`GLKViewController`).